# +1 Damage on some attacks against Treasure Guardians?

Tags: age-of-empires-iii

It seems like some of my attacks against the Outlaw Rifleman and the Outlaw Pistolero deal 1 more damage than they should. Below I will include some of the numbers from the game:

```
Outlaw Rifleman HP before fighting: 270
Villager Ranged Damage: 3
Outlaw Rifleman Resists: 0.3 of ranged damage

Expected Damage:
270 – int(3 * (1 – 0.3)) = 268

Outlaw Rifleman HP after one attack: 267
270 – 267 = 3
Outlaw Rifleman HP after two attacks: 265
267 – 265 = 2
Outlaw Rifleman HP after three attacks: 263
265 – 263 = 2
```

When I use the Hand Attack from a Villager, instead of the Ranged Attack, I get the following results:

```
Outlaw Rifleman HP before fighting: 270
Villager Hand Damage: 10
Outlaw Rifleman Resists: none against Hand Damage

Expected Damage:
270 – 10 = 260

Outlaw Rifleman HP after one attack: 260
270 – 260 = 10
Outlaw Rifleman HP after two attacks: 250
260 – 250 = 10
Outlaw Rifleman HP after three attacks: 240
250 – 240 = 10
```

My question is, is this intended or is it a bug?

Comment: Interesting: Maybe treasure guardian resistances don't take effect until they change out of their idle state (after your initial attack)?

Comment: @onewho I tried this out in a sandbox game. With resistances, my Explorer's damage should be 31.5, rounded down to 31 damage. Without resistances he should deal 45 damage (both of these damage calcs are based on the Explorer's Ranged Attack against the Outlaw Rifleman). But on the first attack, the Explorer dealt 32 damage, and on the next hit, he dealt 31 damage. But then surprisingly he dealt 32 damage on the third hit. I'm so confused. But, to answer you question; the +1 damage doesn't match the damage of an unresisted attack.

Comment: Hmm, well that theory is out then. I wonder if it might be a rounding issue in the code or something then. Another thought, there might be a calculation done when an attacker is at a different "y" position then a target (I know in older Age of Empire games an attacker would get +1 to damage for being on "higher ground"). It's possible this is what might be happening here, though it still seems odd.

Comment: @onewho Well, the damage seems to vary even when they both stand in the same place. And if it was some kind of weird rounding error, wouldn't it affect all the attacks, as it would be the exact same numbers? Besides, I believe it always rounds down damage.

Comment: It may only be a rounding error when taking into account resistance (0.3), especially since damage is constant when there is no resistance to it. I'm only coming up with possible theories as to why the damage seems inconsistent. I don't think there is any definitive answer to this without looking through the actual code to see how things are calculated or talking to one of the programmers and having them answer.

Comment: @onewho Yeah, we might never find out ^^ Thanks for the help.

Comment: @onewho Is it possible that it is some kind of mini-crit or lucky shot-bonus that adds 1 damage? Maybe a boost that only works when Explorers attack Treasure Guardians? It does sound kinda weird though.

Comment: I guess it's possible, thought looking through wiki pages, there is no mention of Explorers having an inherent percentage to deal extra damage. Some nations do have upgrades for their explorers to give them a chance to critical hit, but the difference is way more then 1 extra point of damage.

Comment: @onewho Yeah, nevermind. Shortly after writing that I remembered that the villagers sometimes also got the +1 damage.

Comment: @onewho I found something on a forum. Say you deal 1.5 damage to someone who has 10 HP. That will leave the target at 8.5 HP. Say this number got rounded down, and it tells you the target has 8 HP left, making you think you dealt 2 damage. Then, when you attack it again, you deal another 1,5 damage. 8.5 - 1.5 = 7. Now you think you dealt 1 damage, making it appear like your damage was reduced. I might do some more investigation on this later :D

Comment: I think you're on the right track with that, and that could be very likely explain why you're getting that occasional +1 damage. If you do a little more research on it, you might be able to formulate it into an answer and provide a solid answer to your own question.

Comment: @onewho I did some testing in-game and it checks out.

Comment: @onewho
British Explorer damage against an Outlaw Rifleman / Pistolero: 15 * 3 * (1 - 0.3) = 31.5 damage
Outlaw Rifleman / Pistolero HP after X amounts of attacks:

0 attacks = 270 HP
1 attack: 270 HP - 31.5 = 238.5 ≈ 238 HP
2 attacks: 238.5 HP - 31.5 = 207 HP
3 attacks: 207 HP – 31.5 = 175.5 ≈ 175 HP
4 attacks: 175.5 HP – 31.5 = 144 HP
5 attacks: 144 HP – 31.5 = 112.5 ≈ 112 HP
6 attacks: 112.5 HP – 31.5 = 81 HP
7 attacks: 81 HP – 31.5 = 49.5 HP ≈ 49 HP
8 attacks: 49.5 HP – 31.5 = 18 HP

I checked if this was correct in a sandboxgame, and it is. (Sorry that it got messy, I am new to Arqade)

Comment: Awesome. You did the leg work here; I think you should formulate that into an answer for your original question.